# Passing a parameter to a Component on instantiation

Tags: qml, components, qtquick2

I'm creating `TableViewColumns` during runtime and need to pass the `role` to the `TableViewColumn`.

```
TableView {
    model: myModel

    onModelChanged: {
        var roleList = myModel.customRoleNames
        for ( var i = 0; i < roleList.length; ++i ) {
            var role = roleList[ i ]
            addColumn( /* my column component here */ )
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: columnComponent

    TableViewColumn {
        role: /* ??? */
    }
}
```

How can I feed the `role` to my Component when it's being instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got it. Here is the solution:

```
TableView {
    id: myTableView
    model: myModel

    onModelChanged: {
        var roleList = myModel.customRoleNames
        for ( var i = 0; i < roleList.length; ++i ) {
            var role = roleList[ i ]
            addColumn( columnComponent.createObject ( myTableView, { "role": role } ) )
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: columnComponent

    TableViewColumn { }
}
```

This, of course, works for all properties of `TableViewColumn`, eg.:

```
addColumn( columnComponent.createObject ( myTableView, { "role": myRole, "title": someTitle } ) )
```